# Replace fragment from recycler adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on an android app changing a listview to a recycler view.

**Problem**

Using an example project, I handle my clicks to the recylcer in the adapter view.
However, from this adapter, I am having a very had time calling a new fragment.

```
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //         android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            //        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();

            //       FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            //       FragmentManager manager= getContext().getFragmentManager();

            //       FragmentManager fragmentManager = newsAdapter().getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            //       getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            Log.i("RecyclerViewItemClic", String.valueOf(getLayoutPosition()));

            Log.i("RecyclerViewItemClic", personName.getText().toString());
            String idnum = String.valueOf(personName.getText());
            Log.i("RecyclerViewItemClic", idnum);
            Log.i("RecyclerViewItemClic", personAge.getText().toString());

            if (personName.getText().toString() .equals("1")) {
            /*
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame
                                ,new numNumbersFrag())
                        .commit();


            */
                ((FragmentActivity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new numNumbersFrag())
                        .commit();


            }
        }
```

The above is the code I attempted resulting in the error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentManager
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getFragmentManager()' on a
>   null object

I also get the same error if I try to use getSupportFragmentManager(), or I import fragment instead of the version4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

change

```
((FragmentActivity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new numNumbersFrag())
                    .commit();
```

to

```
((FragmentActivity) view.getContext()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new numNumbersFrag())
                    .commit();
```

because, in

```
public void onClick(View view)
```

view.getContext() will return context which will not be null.

Thanks,

Comment: where is this R.id.content Frame

Comment: it's in the questions.

Answer (score 2):

This may also help u :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    View view = v.getRootView();
    Activity activity = (Activity) view.getContext();
    activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.FrameLayout, fragment).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this on your Adapter class.

```
((FragmentActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, new YourFragment()).addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```